# Typeahed in a drop-down angular js with data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am new to angular js . I have a drop-down , which contains more that 150 values . I want to have a search for the dropdown attached with it . So , I have tried every thing,but i am not able to do . So, my code is -

HTML -

```
<div class="select-container col-sm-12 label-container"
                            ng-disabled="!objectPropertyForm.selectedObjectProperty">
                            <span class="col-sm-4 text-right label-container">
                                <label>Value : </label>
                            </span>
                            <span class="col-sm-8">
                                <select
                                    id="objectPropertyValueSelect"
                                    name="objectPropertyValue"
                                    class="btn btn-start col-sm-12"
                                    ng-model="objectPropertyForm.selectedObjectPropertyValue"
                                    ng-options="range as range.name for range in objectPropertyForm.selectedObjectProperty.rangeList |
                                        filter:objectPropertyRangeFilter
                                        track by range.name">
                                      <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                                </select>
                            </span>
                    </div>
```

controller -

```
 $scope.objectPropertyRangeFilter = function (value) {
                    return !($scope.objectPropertyForm.selectedObjectProperty
                        .values.includes(value.name));
                };
```

if while typing it gives me the values , I want to have only that names in which the typed text is present . Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete
similar solutions

or go for https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete

for which you have to provide $scope.localdata=your autofilldata

Comment: A bit confusion . Because I have never used this . So , Can you tell me how can i use it .

Comment: just import the angular material js and css files.then put html element<md autocomplete> as mentioned in their doc.Put the dropdown items in controller.It should  work.I have used it in several projects.

Comment: I have tried it . Can you tell me how can i use it in my code . My dropdown items are already in controller.So , I have to use it only in html

Comment: if it seems to be complicated use this one https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete

Comment: I have data in controller .But Not getting how to use it in html .

Comment: Can you please provide a link ?

Comment: I want to have a typeahed .